# Dagger 2 Static Injections

Tags: android, dependency-injection, static, dagger-2

Any example of Dagger 2 static injections. I have already tried this : -

```
class A{
 @Inject
 static B b;

 static {
  getAppInstance().getComponent().inject(A.class);
 }

 static anyMethod(){
  b.anotherMethod();  
 }
}
```

---

```
public interface AppComponent{
 void inject(Class<A> aClass);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need it to be static?  A singleton provider should achieve what you need.

Comment: @davehenry You might want it to be static so it can be used withing a static method.

Answer (score 3):

So this is my proposed answer: -

```
class A{
 private static B b = getAppInstance.getComponent().getB();

 static anyMethod(){
  b.anotherMethod();  
 }
}
```

---

```
public interface AppComponent{
 B getB();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation for Dagger 2, https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/dagger-1-migration.html, they removed support for static injections.

> Injected types
>
> Dagger 2 continues to rely on JSR 330 for declaring injection sites.
> All of the types of injection supported by Dagger 1 (field and
> constructor) continue to be supported by Dagger 2, but Dagger 2
> supports method injection as well. **Dagger 2 does not support static
> injection.**